# From php json_encode to jquery decode

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using a well known "hack" (the json encode function) to prevent some characters to mess up my html, im receiving from an API a description field that can content single or double quotes (and other special chars). So:

```
<div class="someThing" data-fulldescription=<?=json_encode($textFromApi);?>>
  ...
</div>
```

Now I read that data field using jquery and then print it inside a div:

```
$('#brand-modal-content').html($(this).parents('.someThing').data('fulldescription'));
```

The problem is, the quotes are now coded by the PHP function, and some characters get replaced by "\u00e8" or "\u00f9", is there a way to reformat the text using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are injecting content into HTML in a very wrong (and even unsafe) way. Do this instead:

```
data-fulldescription="<?=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($textFromApi));?>"
```

This way the JSON will be properly encoded and safely injected no matter what is inside; then, you can decode it like so:

```
var decoded = JSON.parse($(this).parents('.someThing').data('fulldescription'));
```

The combination of these steps will perfectly preserve the JSON no matter what it represents (you can take shortcuts if you assume it's a string, but why not be always 100% safe?). You can then do whatever you want with the decoded value.